# PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions produces BFTask user

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

```
PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email"]) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
            } else {
                print("User logged in through Facebook!")
            }
        } else {
            print("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    }
```

I've set everything up based on Parse's instructions. When I run this code, `user` is of type `BFTask`. It crashes with the following error:

```
-[BFTask isNew]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x135b05970
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: are you sure you are using the latest Facebook and Parse SDK?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I am. I downloaded it straight from Parse's tutorial https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-setup

Comment: Same problem here, did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @SebastiaandeWeert Sorry, it's been awhile since I looked at this. I don't recall the solution. Make sure you've cleaned everything and updated to the latest SDK. Good luck.

Comment: @J.C. Thanks! Got it fixed now without the using of Carthage! ;)